# internal server error when trying to push to Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku

I am have the following project where I am trying to push to Heroku, but I am having an internal server error stating: `Failed to lookup view "index" in views directory "/templates/views"`

[image]

my package.json start code is the following

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node src/app.js"
}
```

and inside app.js I am using express to start the server

```
const app = express();
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000

const publicDir = path.join(__dirname, '../public')
const viewsDir = path.join(__dirname, '../templates/views')
const partialPath = path.join(__dirname, '../templates/partials')

app.set('view engine', 'hbs')
app.set('views', viewsDir)
hbs.registerPartials(partialPath)
app.use(express.static(publicDir))

app.get('', (req, res) => {    
  res.render('index', {
     title: 'Weather app',
     name: 'Bassem alameddine'
   })
})

app.listen(port, () => {
   console.log("server is up on port " + port) 
})
```

can anyone help with this problem please

Thank you

Comment: Did you test it on local?

Comment: Yes it is running smoothly on local with no issues at all